# Quebra de Texto automática

Tags: css, razor

Estou tentando retirar a Quebra de Linha dessa table, porém não sei como efetuar, queria deixa que o nome completo fosse escrito e sem a quebra de linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
    #customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#customers2 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers2 td, #customers2 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #3e4e84;
    color: white;
}

#customers2 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Index:

```
<table id="customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>RG</th>
            <th>Data Entrada</th>
            <th>Data Saida</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Responsável</th>
            <th>Atualizar Saída</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



        @foreach (var v in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@v.Nome</td>
                <td>@v.Rg</td>
                <td>@v.DtIntegracao</td>
                <td>@v.Validade</td>
                <td>@v.Departamento</td>
                <td>@v.Responsavel.Nome</td>

                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Atualizar", "FormUpdate", new { id = v.Id }, new { @class = "icon-edit" })</td>


            </tr>

        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Guilherme, não tem um caractere de quebra de linha ai? O texto não deveria quebrar assim, pois tem tamanho na `td`. Veja também o atributo `padding` da `td`

Comment: Vá no inspecionar elemento e veja o que está acontecendo dentro da linha com o texto. Veja se tem padding a mais nela, se a margem do texto está errada... O que você pode ver no inspecionar?

Comment: em último caso coloca na td esse css `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: eu não entendo muito de css, isso que estou estranhando está quebrando a texto sozinho.

Comment: @RicardoPontual tentei efetuar alteração no `padding` continua a corta o texto ainda.

Comment: Monte um exemplo funcional com o código que fique igual à imagem para podermos analisar melhor, só com esse pedaço do código fica difícil

Comment: @RicardoPontual Já foi efetuado a edição com todo o meu CSS, para facilita o entendimento

Comment: Mas Guilherme, ainda não assim não é um exemplo verificável entende? Não dá pra executar ele e ver o resultado, veja essa outra pergunta por exemplo, onde você consegue replicar e verificar o problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319656/57220

Comment: @RicardoPontual não sei muito bem como efetuar oque eu quero, mas oque eu queria era que em vez de fazer a Quebra de Texto

Comment: Cara com esse CSS que vc colocou na pergunta e com esse HTML a tabela nem chega perto de estar como na imagem que vc postou, assim é impossível simular seu erro para poder te ajudar...

Comment: @hugocsl Acho que agora deve está mais claro a minha duvida.