# Como poderia fazer um pacman mexendo a boca com CSS puro?

Tags: html, css, svg

Com a finalidade de me aprofundar mais no CSS, eu gostaria de saber diferentes formas de fazer animações. Meu objetivo é saber algumas propriedades e recursos novos que o CSS vem implementando.

No caso específico, eu gostaria de saber quais seria a forma mais simples de se fazer um Pacman mexendo a boca.

Eu tenho um pequeno esboço do que pude aprender com SVG e CSS:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <style>
        .circle {
        stroke-dasharray: 151, 158;
        animation: packman .4s infinite ease;
        stroke-width: 50;
        stroke: yellow;
        fill: transparent;
        }

        @keyframes packman{
        
        from {
            stroke-dasharray: 151, 158;
        }
        
        to {
            stroke-dasharray: 158, 158;
        }
        
        }
    </style>
    <circle r='25' cy='50' cx='50' class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

Como eu poderia fazer, de outras formas, essa animação acima?

<sub>**Observação**: Não é um pedido de ajuda para algo real, mas apenas pra aprender</sub>

Comment: Wallace kkkkk ta faltando muita coisa mesmo uhehueuheuhe, mas eu deletei o comentário pois entendi direito qual foi o objetivo da pergunta... tem outras maneiras sim

Comment: e o pacman não tem olhinho ;)

Comment: Resposta editada com mais uma opção, a técnica é até mais simples que a primeira que eu tinha dado...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Em HTML você pode pensar em criar 3 elementos:

- 2 elementos serão a base e usarei `::before` e `::after` (mas pode usar divs também o elemento principal será para agrupar)
- O terceiro elemento será o principal, que recebe os pseudos elementos

Os pseudo elementos `::before` e `::after` serão o "corpo", já o elemento principal será o que irá ajustar a posição dos sub(pseudo)-elementos

O `::after` será a parte de baixo e receberá `border-radius: 100%` para virar um circulo, com `linear-gradient` fazemos ele ficar apenas metade preenchido.

O `::before` será o a parte de cima, ele é idêntico, você poderia simplesmente inverter a ordem das cores no `linear-gradient`, mas eu pessoalmente acho muito mais pratico fazer isto usando `transform: rotate(180deg);` que vai virar o elemento de ponta cabeça (eu entendo que dá para rotacionar de diversas formas, mas o efeito é o mesmo no final):

O exemplo estático sem animação para ver o corpo pronto:

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

/* todos elementos devem ter a mesma altura, a não ser que queira aplicar margens */
.pacman-css, .pacman-css::before, .pacman-css::after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.pacman-css {
     position: relative;
}

.pacman-css::before, .pacman-css::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;

    /*posiciona ambos elementos no mesmo lugar*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* aplica a borda para transformar em um circulo */
    border-radius: 100%;

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
                                           rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
                                           yellow 50%);
    /*Aplica o amarelo do 50% até o 100%, ou seja NÃO é necessário aplicar yellow 100% depois */
}

/* o before deve ser a de cima */
.pacman-css::before {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pacman-css">
</div>
```

Pronto, temos a base do nosso pacman, a segunda parte é aplicar a animação, mas para isso é preciso criar uma animação para a parte de cima e outra para a de baixo.

O `::before` vai animar normalmente a partir da rotação `0deg` ir até a rotação desejada (no exemplo apliquei `30deg` mas você pode mudar isso) e depois voltar ao `0deg` (sei que dá pra ajustar o retorno no próprio `animate`, mas o efeito é o mesmo e é para fins didáticos, sugestões comentem)

O `::after` vai animar a parte de baixo, portanto ele vai começar do `180deg` e você pode aplicar o valor menor para que a parte de baixo faça a rotação invertida, no exemplo usei `150deg`, você pode ajustar isso também.

Você também pode mudar a movimentação da parte de baixo ou da cima, inclusive pode aplicar diferentes velocidades, trocando o `.5s` de cada `animate`, fica a seu critério, o exemplo é simplório e totalmente customizável:

```css
body {
    background: black;
}

.pacman-css, .pacman-css::before, .pacman-css::after {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.pacman-css {
     position: relative;
}

.pacman-css::before, .pacman-css::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
                                           rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
                                           yellow 50%);
}

.pacman-css::before {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     animation: anima-pacman-cima .5s infinite;
}

.pacman-css::after {
     animation: anima-pacman-baixo .5s infinite;
}

@keyframes anima-pacman-cima
{
    0%   { transform: rotate(180deg); }
    50%  { transform: rotate(150deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}

@keyframes anima-pacman-baixo
{
    0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);  }
    50%  { transform: rotate(30deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg);  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pacman-css">
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo exemplo também! Talves até mais simples

Answer (score 31):

Seguem exemplos apenas com CSS.

## **Opção 1:** *Feita com border-radius*

Nessa opção não precisa usar `position` `relative` ou `absolute`, nem precisa de colocar as `div`s dentro de um *container* São apenas duas divs com `border-radius`.

Depois vc faz um `keyframe` simples rotacionando uma para um lado e outra para o outro e o pac-man faz o movimento!

```css
body { background: black; }

.topo, .base {
    background-color: gold;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
    animation: comex 500ms linear infinite;
}
.base {
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
    animation: comey 500ms linear infinite;
}
@keyframes comex {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
}
@keyframes comey {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topo"></div>
<div class="base"></div>
```

---

## **Opção 2:** *feita com bordas*

A bagulho é simples, são duas divs sobrepostas com `position:absolute`. Uma tem as bordas de cima amarela e as bordas de baixo transparente. A segunda `div` é ao contrário com a parte de cima transparente.

Aqui é o mesmo principio dos `@keyframes` girando as `div`s inversamente. Repare que é tudo feito com bordas...

Segue o exemplo.

```css
html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, tomato, skyblue);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.pac, .boca {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 100px solid gold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.pac {

    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    animation: comex 500ms linear infinite;
}
.boca {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    animation: comey 500ms linear infinite;
}
@keyframes comex {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-75deg);
    }
}
@keyframes comey {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="pac"></div>
    <div class="boca"></div>
</div>
```

---

## No Futuro

**OBS:** Em breve o CSS "4" deve implementar o `conic-gradiente()` e com ele esse tipo de animação vai ficar mais fácil. Aqui está a documentação https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#conic-gradients

Como ainda não é possível animar gradientes (seja ele de qualquer tipo), vc tem que fazer uma animação por *steps* mudando os valores na mão para cada fração da animação. Logicamente quanto mais steps vc fizer, mais fluida vai ficar a animação, eu fiz esse exemplo apenas para fins didáticos, aqui tem a documentação do Mozilla sobre o `conic-gradient` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima (***Esse código não funciona no FireFox no momento***, *mas muito em breve vai funcionar no **Edge**, pois ele está migrando a *enginee* para Chrommium*)

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
}
.pac {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(gold 90deg, transparent 90deg, transparent 90deg, gold 90deg);
    /* background: gold; */
    animation: pac 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes pac {
    0% {
        background: conic-gradient(gold 45deg, transparent 45deg, transparent 125deg, gold 125deg);
    }
    25% {
        background: conic-gradient(gold 65deg, transparent 65deg, transparent 105deg, gold 105deg);
    }
    50% {
        background: conic-gradient(gold 90deg, transparent 90deg, transparent 90deg, gold 90deg);
    }
    75% {
        background: conic-gradient(gold 65deg, transparent 65deg, transparent 105deg, gold 105deg);
    }
    100% {
        background: conic-gradient(gold 45deg, transparent 45deg, transparent 125deg, gold 125deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="pac"></div>
```

Artigo sobre o conic-gradiente: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-conic-gradient/

**Polyfill:** https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/

- Exemplo de aplicação para o conic-gradiente. *Para fazer o **Pacman** seria algo como feito no terceiro exemplo.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Suporte atual dos Browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients

Dos maiores apenas o **FireFox** ainda não aceita o **`conic-gradients`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mais lindo que CSS é a criatividade que a pessoa precisa ter para conseguir aplicar tudo o que o CSS propõe. Fico fascinado, de verdade!

Comment: @PedroAugusto cara CSS é tipo a Matrix, depois que vc entra nela e começa a entender de fato o que se está fazendo vc fica fascinado. Além disso com CSS quase sempre tem mais de um jeito de fazer a mesma coisa, realmente é muito legal. Tmj

Comment: Perfeito a sua resposta.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda valeu a força! E o mais legal é que já é possível usar do IE10 para frente! Depois quando vier os conic-gradients as possibilidades com CSS vão ficar ainda mais divertidas :)

Comment: @hugocsl sim principalmente para os joguinhos.

Comment: Logo alguém faz um jogo com HTML + CSS puro! kk

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- uma animação mais complexa acho que da pra fazer, agora um joguinho acho que fica complicado sem um JS na história rss

Comment: CSS tem evoluído bastante! E o limite dele começou a ser quebrado com a possibilidade de executar cálculos e afins...

Comment: É verdade, o que mais sinto falta no CSS é uma forma dinâmica de fazer uns addClass, toogleClasses e tingir elemrntos pai ou em outra hierarquia de elementos, (tipo em outro escopo), se ele fizesse isso nativamente, ai é que o jQuery ia perder ainda mais espaço...